# Resizing Page Vertically Centered Content

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to build a page similar to [this](http://www.squarespace.com/stories), that when the browser window is resized the content stays vertically centered.

Here's what I've got so far:

http://codepen.io/realph/pen/svuHI

I'm trying to get the `.marketing` element to stay vertically centered. While the footer sticks to the bottom of the page, but moves up when resizing the browser window also.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `.marketing` CSS

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -50px; /* change this to half of the height of the element  */
```